# Make jumplist behave like stack?

Tags: jumplist

I use CTRL-O and CTRL-I heavily to move between previously visited positions. These commands rely on the jumplist.

It makes sense to me to visualize the jumplist as a stack of my position history. Thus, I'm surprised that the jumplist is effectively indexed by file and line number, which you can deduce from the vim docs.

In `motion.txt`:

> If the same line was already in the jump list, it is removed.
> The result is that when repeating CTRL-O you will get back to old positions
> only once.

It's a bit annoying to me because it doesn't preserve the exact history. Maybe I'm not conceptualizing the feature as intended. My questions:

1. Is there a way to customize this behaviour?
2. More importantly to me, what's the reason it was implemented this way?

### Example

Take some file with >= 3 lines, do the following movement commands, and view the line numbers in the jumplist.

```
1G
2G
3G
2G
G "some movement to persist the last jump to the jumplist
```

#### Expected

```
1
2
3
2
```

#### Actual

```
1
3
2
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3):

The 'jumpoptions' option is not yet supported in Vim (it is only supported in Neovim). The following pull request was created to add this support:

https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/7738

But this is not merged (refer to the the discussion in the PR).

Comment: just curious, why did you close your PR?

Comment: Merged in 9.0.1921.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `jumpoptions` is the setting which you're looking for. Put the following into your `vimrc`/`init.vim`:

```
set jumpoptions=stack
```

For more information, take a look into `:h 'jumpoptions'`.